# SSRS rounds to whole numbers, but includes 2 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, rdl

I have some SQL, of which the part in question is:

```
sum(Minutes)/60.0 Hrs
```

In SQL Server Management Studio, my database returns:

```
14.500000
```

In SSRS, my report displays:

```
14.00
```

My RDL's cell that displays this value has this definition:

```
=Fields!Hrs.Value
```

The cell's textbox properties have been defined as a Number, no checkboxes selected, 2 decimal points.

So, the question is, why is my report only outputting 14.00 rather than 14.50 and how can I fix it?

Edit: It may be worth mentioning that the cell data is strangely left-justified, despite not having told it to justify.

Comment: What does the Dataset definition look like in the RDL file for that particular field? I put a quick test together with a query like yours (i.e. `avg(field)/60.0`, based on an `int` type field) and the rounding was fine - in the RDL the relevant element in the Dataset was `<rd:TypeName>System.Decimal</rd:TypeName>`, which is what you'd expect.

Comment: The only "rd" that I see in the .rdl is <rd:DefaultName>. The dataset definition for this field is "<Field Name="Hrs"><DataField>ActualHrs</DataField><rd:UserDefined>true</rd:UserDefined></Field>"

Comment: **Test 1** Double check the database links to verify that SSMS and your report points to same database. **Test 2** Check the data in report dataset (not in SSMS) and check if it shows 14 or 14.5.

Comment: Long shot maybe, but your Dataset field `Hrs` is pointing to the database field `ActualHrs`, not `Hrs` as the rest of the question indicates... Is this the correct field?

Comment: Anup-> I copied my DataSet into another DataSet and output the value for the column in question to a new table in my report. It correctly shows 14.5.

Comment: Ian-> That may have been me goofing up when copying the data here. I tried to simplify the names and must have become less careful when copying for the comments than I was in the original post.

Comment: I just ended up letting the SQL give me minutes and then divide by 60 whenever I need to output data rather than handling the division in SQL. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing its definition to this:

```
=Format(CDbl(Fields!myFields.Value),"00.00")
```

Comment: Just try this, select your textbox, in the properties select Format and enter N2, also remove any earlier formatting you have for this text box

Comment: Sadly, no, no change. Still showing 14.00 rather than 14.50 with N2. To make sure I was doing the right thing, I also tried N3, which gave me 14.000.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `CInt` instead of `CDbl` which will always try to return an integer. Hence the `.00` at the end of your expression. Try:

```
=Format(CDbl(Fields!myFields.Value),"F2")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the textbox properties of the cell, and after selecting the type number,  you change decimals two zero it should work regardless of the content of the cell.
Like this:
[image]